# "Expected token ')' got int" in C

Tags: c, qt-creator

I have a small problem with a code written below. VS 2010 compiles it, runs and I get the predicted result. But when I tried to compile this code with Qt Creator I get this warning every time: "Expected token ')' got int". Yes, program will be run by Qt Creator, but the program will blow up. What's wrong with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 2

int **getAddresses(int amount, ...)
{
    static int *arr[ARR_SIZE] = {};
    va_list vl;

    if(amount > 0)
    {
        va_start(vl, amount);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            *(arr + sizeof(int) * i) = va_arg(vl, int*);  //This one is highlighted by the Qt Creator.
        }
        va_end(vl);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return arr;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 3, b = 5;

    getAddresses(ARR_SIZE, &a, &b);
    printf("BEFORE: %d, %d\n", a, b);

    int **res = getAddresses(0), i;
    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        *(*(res + sizeof(int) * i)) += 5;
    }

    printf("AFTER: %d, %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your answers beforehand.

ADDED: Qt Creator highlights this line of code *(arr + sizeof(int) * i) = va_arg(vl, int*);

Furthermore Dev++ is able to run this code without any warning and errors or crushing.

GCC is able to compile it under Fedora linux 14:

```
[Admin@localhost testerprog]$ gcc tester.c -o tester
[Admin@localhost testerprog]$ ls
tester  tester.c
[Admin@localhost testerprog]$ ./tester
BEFORE: 3, 5
AFTER: 8, 10
[Admin@localhost testerprog]$
```

GCC version is 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)

Comment: Do you know on which line? If yes, please add that in a comment in your code.

Comment: Compiles in gcc too. Does the error occur in a header file?

Comment: Line number of error, please.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Qt creator highlights this one: *(arr + sizeof(int) * i) = va_arg(vl, int*);      But when program crushes, even in debug mode can be found no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--- Edited, as the original post is a bit wrong, but the same line is likely the cause ---

Since the error specifically mentioned finding an int instead of a closing parenthesis, I would suspect the offending line is

```
        *(arr + sizeof(int) * i) = va_arg(vl, int*);
```

And while your code is valid C / C++, I would reverse my suspicion that the VS compiler made a mistake, but offer a similar suspicion that the Qt compiler either

1. Has a bug in it and is expecting a R value, not a type.
2. Has wrapped `va_arg` references in some other `qt_xxx` style wrapper to allow proper compiling in the QT framework.

--- Original post follows ---

int is a keyword in C / C++ so you cannot use it as a variable safely.  It seems that the line

```
        *(arr + sizeof(int) * i) = va_arg(vl, int*);
```

asks for the value of the address held by a variable, *int*, not the value referenced by an int pointer.  Odds are that the VS compiler's error checking isn't as robust, leading to silent acceptance of the error.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, and I realized the mistake just after I posted, but I updated it immediately (as you were commenting).  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don't say C/C++ please. This is C, not C++, as you can see by the headers (stdarg.h, not cstdarg)

Comment: You are right about the line of code which is highlighted by Qt Creator.

Comment: Then odds are excellent it is the `int*` in `va_arg(vl, int*)` the Qt Creator is choking on.  It might be this bug https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTSDK-145 which is fixed.  Probably the qt compiler sees the pointer and thinks it is a dereference of a variable, instead of a pointer type.

Comment: @Edwin Buck, thank you. I guess, I have to update Qt SDK and try once again.

Comment: @user1415536 I don't know if this helps, but could you try including `<varargs.h>` instead of `<stdarg.h>`

Comment: @MrLister: I got this error message:  "GCC no longer implements <varargs.h>." in Qt Creator

Answer (score 0):

```
    va_start(vl, amount);
    int i;
```

That's not C.

Definitions must occur before code.

VC running it's sort of C/C++ mode won't mind.  A C-only compiler will object.

Comment: It's because the compiler is MSVC which only does C90. Charles Bailey's deleted answer is in fact the best one here.

Comment: Did Banahan et al produce a version of "The C Book" for C99?  best textbook I ever read.

Comment: @David: but the error occurs with Qt, *not* with MSVC - and I think that's because MSVC gives this the C++ treatment and doesn't mind the location of the definition.

Comment: @David: I think OP indicates Qt issues a warning, because he can run the code.  Qt could just be dealing with it and define the variable at that point - and it crashes because there's a bug elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @ Blank Xavier: No, this code that you can see here is only code in the program.

Comment: @MrLister: mingw for Qt Creator.

Comment: By the way, in Fedora Linux, gcc will compile this code and the program will work.

Comment: @BlankXavier: I considered this, but I can't find any. `*(*(res + sizeof(int) * i)) += 5;` - Nope. Here is accessed the first column(0) of the two dimensional array. The idea of the program was very simple: the user sends two addresses of the local variables to this function. After that, by accessing this function with no arguments(besides the first one 0), user can retrieve those addresses and change variables. This one is for cases, when the use of global variables is not acceptable for some reasons. Three of four compilers will handle this code nicely.